# Program not printing correct output in specific cases

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

here is my code:

```
def bizzBuzzAnalysis(n):
    n = int(input())
    bizz = 0
    buzz = 0
    if(n%7==0):
        print(n, "is divisible by 7. Add a bizz!")
        bizz+=1

    if(n%9==0):
        print(n, "is divisible by 9. Add a buzz!")
        buzz+=1

    r = str(n)
    for i in range(len(r)):
        if r[i] == "7":
            print("Digit is 7, add a bizz!")
            bizz+=1
        if r[i] == "9":
            print("Digit is 9, add a buzz!")
            buzz+=1
    if(bizz==0 & buzz == 0):
        print(r)
    else:
        print(("Bizz! " * bizz) + ("Buzz! " *buzz))


# input and function test
n = 0
bizzBuzzAnalysis(n)
```

With an input of 99, the program will still print that the number is divisible by and contains the number 9. However, it will only print the number instead of the phrases it should be printing. It seems to be the case for most numbers that contain a 9. Is there something wrong with my if statements?

Comment: Your code includes code for `7` too, is this just an issue for `9`s?

Comment: yeah, sorry I should've made it more clear. The output prints fine for 7s, just not for 9s.

Answer (score 3):

`&` is not the logical `and` operator. Your expression is parsed as

```
if bizz == (0 & buzz) == 0:
```

which is equivalent to

```
if bizz == 0 == 0:
```

so the actual value of `buzz` is irrelevant. With `n == 99`, the value of `bizz` is, indeed, 0, so only the number itself is printed.

Don't use `&` when you mean `and`:

```
if bizz == 0 and buzz == 0:
```

Comment: Figured it was an easy fix, thank you so much! Seems like i got stuck in java mode and thought just "&" would work after "&&" didn't